Let $z \sim N(0,I)$ and $A_1, \ldots, A_N \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}$. Is $U = \max_{j=1,\ldots N} \lVert A_j z \rVert_2$ subgaussian?
Let $z \sim N(0,I)$ with $z \in \mathbb{R}^d$(i.e. $z_1, \ldots, z_d$ are i.i.d $N(0,1)$). Let  $A_1, \ldots, A_N \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}$ be fixed matrices.
Then is $U = \max_{j=1,\ldots N} \lVert A_j z \rVert_2$ subgaussian?
My attempt:
Bound each $\lVert A_j z \rVert_2$ by $\lVert A_j \rVert \lVert z \rVert_2$. Let $C_N = \max_{j=1,\ldots, N} \lVert A_j \rVert$.
Then,
$$\max_{j=1, \ldots, N} \lVert A_j z \rVert_2 \leq C_N \max_{j=1, \ldots, N} \lVert z \rVert_2  \leq C_N \sum_{j=1}^N \lVert z_j \rVert_2$$.
$ C_N \sum_{j=1}^N  \lVert z_j \rVert_2$ is subgaussian by the fact that $\lVert z_j \rVert_2$ is. Hence, $\max_{j=1, \ldots, N} \lVert A_j z \rVert_2$ is also sub-gaussian.
Thank you.
